# Why argument conversion is not considered when calling a templated function?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class and a friend `operator*` function

```
StereoSmp<TE> operator* (const StereoSmp<TE>& a, TE b)
```

I use it with `TE=float` but I need to multiply a `StereoSmp<float> * double`
I think that should be possibile because it should converts `double` to `float` automatically and works but I get the error:

> ```
> no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘StereoSmp<float>’ and
>     ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<double> >::value_type {aka double}’) 
> deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘TE’ (‘float’ and ‘double’)
> ```

Why it doesn't convert double to float automatically? And what can I do to allow the automatic conversion between types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't make your friend a template.

```
template<class TE>
struct StereoSmp {
  friend StereoSmp operator* (const StereoSmp& a, TE b) {
    return multiply( a, b ); // implement here
  }
};
```

this is a non-template friend to each type instance of the template `StereoSmp`.  It will consider conversions.

Template functions don't consider conversions, they simply do exact pattern matching.  Overload resolution is already insane enough in C++.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how does it work exactly? Why I can write it but I can't write a function like: `int fun(vector& v)` without specify vector template type?

Comment: @Andrea993 Within the body of a template, the name of the template is short hand for "the template type instance type".  This operator can be found only via ADL/Koenig lookup, and works sort of a quirk of how ADL/Koenig lookup/friend function declarations work.  It lets you inject a non-template function per template instance instantiated that can only be found via ADL on an instance of the template type.

Answer (score 3):

[Keep it simple, silly:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

```
template<class U>
StereoSmp<TE> operator* (const StereoSmp<TE>& a, U b);
```

or if it applies:

```
StereoSmp<TE> a {/* ... */};
double b = /* ... */;
auto c = a * static_cast<float>(b);
```

---

> Why it doesn't convert double to float automatically?

Because template deduction happens *before* possible conversions are taken into consideration. If you call `a*b` with `a` a `StereoSmp<float>` and `b` a `double`, template substitution will fail before a `float` to `double` conversion can be considered, and name lookup will continue, until failing short of candidates.

This process is called [Template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template).

Answer (score 2):

Although Yakk's answer is probably the best in this particular scenario, I want to point out that you can prevent this deduction conflict and get your expected result (pass `StereoSmp<float>`, deduce `TE` as `float`) by making the other argument ineligible for use in deduction:

```
StereoSmp<TE> operator* (const StereoSmp<TE>& a, remove_reference<TE>::type b)
```

Related reading: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3766.html

Comment: Neat trick! (but urgh - if I came across this I would hope there was a comment nearby...)

Comment: @davmac: The linked paper suggests better names such as `omit_from_deduction`.  `std::remove_reference` simply happens to be in the Standard so no helper code is needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Why it doesn't convert double to float automatically? And what can I do to allow the automatic conversion between types?

This isn't a conversion problem, it's a template parameter inference issue. Since the declaration is of the form:

```
StereoSmp<TE> operator* (const StereoSmp<TE>& a, TE b)
```

... and the operands are of type `StereoSmp<float>` and `double`, the C++ inference rules do not work, because they do not take into account that a `double` is convertible to a `float`. These rules are specified by the language specification; the reason *why* they don't take potential conversions into account is probably because "it would make deduction *very* complicated, otherwise". The rules are already complex enough!

You can of course cast your `double` parameter to a `float` and it will work fine. Also, you could make the `operator*` a member function of `StereoSmp`, or you could independently parameterise the types of the type parameters:

```
template <class TE, class U> StereoSmp<TE> operator* (const StereoSmp<TE>& a, U b);
```